# crypto-js module is imported but does not work as expected

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, node-modules, cryptojs

I work on a project which use typescript and es6 syntax. I have installed the module crypto-js `npm install crypto-js` and his typescript type `npm install @types/crypto-js`.

I import it then into my file like this:

`import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';`

But when I tried to use it like in the documentation:

`console.log(CryptoJS.MD5('my message'));`

It show me an Object structure instead of an unreadable string:

```
WordArray.init {words: Array(4), sigBytes: 16}
sigBytes: 16
words: Array(4)
    0: -1952005731
    1: -1042352784
    2: 804629695
    3: 720283050
    length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you reference the output from calling the MD5 function which, when passed to `typeof` returns its type as 'object'.

Though it seems poorly documented, you can reach the string representation of the MD5 value using:

```
console.log(CryptoJS.MD5('my message').toString())
```

which produces: `"8ba6c19dc1def5702ff5acbf2aeea5aa"`

If you plan to run your code using NodeJS, you might consider its native `crypto` module rather than `crypto-js`.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const h = crypto.createHash('md5')
h.update('my message')
console.log(h.digest('hex'))
```

which also prints: `"8ba6c19dc1def5702ff5acbf2aeea5aa"`

The benefit of using NodeJS' native [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding) here is that, like all native modules, it is bundled into the NodeJS runtime and so doesn't need to be loaded in from an external module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't think the documentation would be so poor for such a downloaded project. Anyway I follow your advice using the native module.